# How to transfer data using delegate in VIPER structure

Tags: ios, swift, viper-architecture

I have two pages, page one is `loginPage`, another is `MainViewPage`.

I wanna transfer `userInfo` (`UserName` and `Password`) from page one to two, I'm using VIPER structure.

I already get the `userInfo` in the second page, but when I'm using `Presenter` function to update `UILabel` in `SecondPage`, the progress is broken, it shows following error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MainViewModuleView: UIViewController, MainViewModuleViewProtocol
{
    var presenter: MainViewModulePresenterProtocol?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var userInfo: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        print(NSHomeDirectory()as NSString)
    }
    
    func updateLabel(text:String){
        print(text)
        userInfo.text = text
    }
}
```

Here is my `Presenter`:

```
import Foundation

class MainViewModulePresenter: MainViewModulePresenterProtocol, MainViewModuleInteractorOutputProtocol
{
    weak var view: MainViewModuleViewProtocol?
    var interactor: MainViewModuleInteractorInputProtocol?
    var wireFrame: MainViewModuleWireFrameProtocol?
    var delegate: MainModuleDelegate?
    
    init() {}    
}

extension MainViewModulePresenter: MainModuleDelegate{
    
    func sendLoginUser(userName: String) {
        print("MainViewModulePresenter?.sendLoginUser: " + userName)
        let text = userName
        view?.updateLabel(text: text)
    }
}
```

The text in both `Presenter` and `MainView` has value, but when it call `updateLabel` function, the progress was broken. The Code of this Demo in [this repository](https://github.com/paboo199148/VIPERDemo)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a case of the MainViewModuleView not being loaded/instantiated from the storyboard.

It seems to lose its connection with the storyboard shortly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your label is uninitialized during the assignment. I think your method is being called before `viewDidLoad`.